# Why does Excel generating an empty element in xml file when no data is present for that element in the datasource

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2013 to generate an xml file according to an xsd schema provided by our authorities for Intrastat reporting purposes.

Everything works fine except for the situation when I have no data for a specific element, which is defined as optional according to the xsd schema provided.

According to the Excel documentation "Empty items are not created when blank cells exist for an optional element, but empty items are created when blank cells exist for a required element."

So, as my element is optional, Excel should not create an empty element, but in my case it does.

Here is the definition of the element:

```
    <!--Supplementary Unit Details Type-->
 <xsd:complexType name="InsSupplUnitsInfoType" >
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="SupplUnitCode" type="xsd:token" minOccurs="0">
 <xsd:annotation>
 <xsd:documentation>
 The Supplumentary Units code taken from the related nomenclature.
 </xsd:documentation>
 </xsd:annotation>
 </xsd:element>
 <xsd:element name="QtyInSupplUnits" type="PositiveLongType" minOccurs="0" />
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

The element appears as optional in the definition of the main reporting element, as you can see below (in the last element declaration):

```
    <!--The Abstract Declaration Item Type-->
 <xsd:complexType name="InsDeclarationItemType" abstract="true">
 <xsd:sequence>

 <xsd:element name="Cn8Code" type="Cn8CodificationType" />

 <xsd:element name="InvoiceValue" type="PositiveLongType"> 
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="StatisticalValue" minOccurs="0" type="PositiveLongType" >
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="NetMass" type="PositiveLongType" >
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="NatureOfTransactionACode" type="xsd:token" >
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="NatureOfTransactionBCode" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:token" >
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="DeliveryTermsCode" type="xsd:token" >
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="ModeOfTransportCode" type="xsd:token" >
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="CountryOfOrigin" type="CountryType" />

 <xsd:element name="InsSupplUnitsInfo" minOccurs="0" type="InsSupplUnitsInfoType" />
 </xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:attribute name="OrderNr" type="PositiveIntType"/>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

However, the output xml file is including the below empty element

```
<InsSupplUnitsInfo/>
```

even if its both child elements are empty.

This is generating an error in the application in which I'm entering the xml file. So, I need to understand why this happens in order to be able to get rid off this unwanted empty element which normally should not be generated according to the Excel rules.

Comment: Hello Emil and welcome to the site.  We like to keep things pretty to-the-point around here, so I went ahead and edited your question.  If you aren't happy with the changes please feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Hello, it's curious that nobody replied to this question..I've posted it on the MS Excel developer forum with the same result..so nobody who is using Excel to export xml data encountered this situation ?

Comment: At the moment the question has only been viewed 121 times, you are probably not getting an answer because of the lack of exposure.